# The number of elements of order $2$ in a quotient group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. The number of elements of order $2$ in $G/N$ may be larger than $G$. For example, if $G$ is a quaternion group of order $8$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup with $|N|=2$, then the number of elements of order $2$ in $G/N$ is larger than $G$.

Now, suppose that $G$ is a non-solvable group and $Rad(G)\neq 1$ is the solvable radical of $G$. My question is: Is there any example such that involutions of $G/Rad(G)$ are larger than involutions from $G$?

Comment: Isn't $|G/N|\le |G|$?

Comment: @Devo Yes of course, but how is that relevant?

Comment: By "larger than $G$" I misinterpreted as  "larger than $|G|$", whereas I see it is something like "larger than $G$'s involutions", @DerekHolt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, $G={\rm SL}(2,q)$ for any odd $q\ge 5$, with ${\rm Rad}(G) = Z(G) \cong C_2$.

Then $G$ has the unique involution $-I_2$, but $G/Z(G) = {\rm PSL}(2,q)$ has lots of involutions.